# url rewriting using global.aspx in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, url-rewriting

My requested url is /abc/default.aspx
i want to rewrite this url like /abc/Company/default.aspx
here is my code

```
Dim CompanyName As String = "BSNL"
            Dim URL_path As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path
            If URL_path.Contains("/abc") Then
                Context.RewritePath(URL_path.Replace("/abc/BSNL/default.aspx", "/abc"))
            End If
```

Comment: i am unable to redirect url and rewritting..can any one help me.thanks in advanced